# How to register IFileProvider for the dependency injection in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following class in order to be able to serve the files from resources of the referenced project:

```
public class ConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<StaticFileOptions>
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment environment;

    public ConfigureOptions(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, StaticFileOptions options)
    {
        options.ContentTypeProvider = options.ContentTypeProvider ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        if (options.FileProvider == null && environment.WebRootFileProvider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
        }
        options.FileProvider = options.FileProvider ?? environment.WebRootFileProvider;

        var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, "Resources");
        options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(options.FileProvider, filesProvider);
    }
}
```

This setup is then included into the `startup.cs`:

```
services.ConfigureOptions(typeof(Emails.ConfigureOptions));
```

Now, I have a service that receives `IFileProvider` via constructor:

```
public HtmlToEmailConverter(IFileProvider fileProvider)
{
    this.fileProvider = fileProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileProvider));
}
```

I am getting the DI error when I try to use my service:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider' while attempting to
>   activate ' ... '.

So, I need to register service for the `IFileProvider` but would like to get the instance that rest of asp.net core infrastructure is using -
the one that now can serve both physical and embedded files.

How to register service for the `IFileProvider`?

In other words, how to get to that IFileProvider that the rest of the application is using when serving static files.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find any clues online on how to solve this, although the solution is pretty simple and straightforward.

I have made the function that resolves `StaticFileOptions` and those options appears that already have ready-to-use composite file provider (in my case both physical and embedded files provider):

```
private IFileProvider GetFileProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var staticFileOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<StaticFileOptions>>();
    var staticFileProvider = staticFileOptions.Value.FileProvider;
    return staticFileProvider;
}
```

[image: Debug output]

And then just register this function to service collection:

```
services.AddSingleton(GetFileProvider);
```